# Make a button always visible on scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a form of many fields(long page), and each time I want to submit I have to scroll to the buttom to click on submit. I want a trick in which I can always see the submit button, without going to the bottom of the page. (liek making the submit button float on the page for instance)

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: You'll need to provide code of what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your CSS, try ...

```
.SubmitButton {
  position: fixed;
  top: 100px;
  left: 10px;
}
```

I've made several assumptions ... name of the class on your button, where you want it to be top/left.

Comment: Thank you, I needed to know the fixed position property. I don't know why some other "smart" people are asking me to give them something I don't know at all.

Comment: Generally, we like to see "some" code ... to show what you've got, even if you haven't tried anything.  Although, I will admit they can get a bit pushy about it.  Glad I could help.

Comment: @anyavacy Haha, I guess I'm one of those "smart" people! ;) Requesting that you provide code of what you have already tried is for a good reason: it makes the question more useful for other users that encounter the problem and makes it easier for someone to provide a relevant answer. The comments from Pavlo and myself were to help you understand why the question was being downvoted. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask may give you some pointers for future questions. Still, glad rfornal was able to help you.

Comment: I agree ... the code helps in that I could have used an ID or Class that is more directly aligned with what you are actually doing.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#yourButton {position: fixed}
```

Answer (score 1):

To have elements always visible, set their position to `fixed`.

```
.long-form-button {
  position: fixed;
}
```

Note that you will want to set `top`, `bottom`, `left` and/or `right` too.

Also, it's probably going to look better if you position a whole container/section with the button inside otherwise the button will just float in the middle of nowhere.